# How to extract the coefficients of various n-th degree polynomial models and store them into a 1D array?

Tags: r, for-loop, coefficients

I have a collection of sixth-degree polynomial regression models from which I want to gather only the coefficients.

I have a large dataset that contains 3 columns: the first one is an arbitrary parameter that acts as a flag, the second is the input, and third is the output.

I subsetted my dataset according to my parameters, so I have 10 smaller datasets. My models arose from these subsets.

As an example:

```
 #-----"Dummy" Dataset-----
 a = seq(1:100) #act as input
 b = a + rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 20) #act as output
 df = as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
 colnames(df) = c("input", "output")
 #
 #-----Subsets-----
 df_1_XlessThen50 = subset(df, x< 50) #example of subsetting. In this 
                                      #case I used the x values itself as threshold 
                                      #for subsetting just for simplicity. 
                                      #In reality, I use the first  column of my dataframe(parameter). 
 df_2_XmoreThen50 = subset(df, x >= 50) #second subset. In other words,
                                        #for every parameter, I will divide that subset
                                        #into two smaller ones.
 #
 #-----Models-----
 model_3_ab.1 = lm(output ~ poly(input, 6, raw = T), data = df_1_XlessThen50)
 model_3_ab.2 = lm(output ~ poly(input, 6, raw = T), data = df_2_XmoreThen50)
```

My models's names follow a pattern: "model" + parameter + "_ab." + id number.
I should clarify that the "id number" indicates which of the two models for  every parameter I will consider. (Theses smaller datasets within every parameter are the results of subsetting according to a pre-determined threshold.)

What I have now is a collection of models like these two above for every parameter in my dataset. I have 10 parameters, hence, 20 models.

I want to gather only the coefficients of every model and store them into a matrix or dataframe. To achieve that, I tried:

```
  parameter = c(2,4,6,7,9,11,33,35,37,50)
  myData = array()

  for (i in parameter){ #Loop over all parameters
     for (j in 1:2){ #Loop over the pair of models for each parameter
        for ( k in 1:6){ #Loop over my model's coefficient  
            aux =  paste("model",i,"ab.",j, sep = "") 
            aux = get(aux)
            myData[i,j,k] = aux$coefficients[k]
        }
     }
  }
```

However, I keep getting the same error:

> Error in myData[i, j, k] = aux$coefficients[k] : 
>     incorrect number of subscripts

With this error, I can't advance into my goal, which is to write a .txt with one single column formatted as such:

> A(2,1,1) = first order coefficient for the first model related to parameter 2
>
> B(2,2,1) = second order coefficient for the first model related to parameter 2
>
> C(2,3,1)
>
> ...
>
> G(2,7,1)
>
> A(2,1,2)

where in (M, N, O): M is the parameter, N is the the coefficient of the N-th degree (N = 7 is the  intercept), and O is either 1 or 2, respectively, the first or second model in each pair of models for every parameter.

It'd be nice to get help/guidance for the whole problem, but I'll already be grateful if I can get past the part where I want to store my coefficients in a matrix using for-loops. Thanks

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-13/topics/lmList

Comment: Thanks, @Roland. I had already taken a look at lmList and it doesn't serve my purposes, or at least, I can't see how it'd do so in the way I want. But thanks anyway for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I mean:

```
set.seed(42)
a1 = seq(1:100) #act as input
a2 <- runif(100)
b = a1 + a2 + rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 20) #act as output
df = data.frame(input1 = a1, 
                input2 = a2, 
                output = b)
df$flag <- a1 <= 50

library(reshape2)
df <- melt(df, id.vars = c("output", "flag"))

library(lme4)
df$flag_par <- interaction(df$flag, df$variable)

fits <- lmList(output ~ poly(value, 2, raw = TRUE) | flag_par, data = df)
coef(fits)
#             (Intercept) poly(value, 2, raw = TRUE)1 poly(value, 2, raw = TRUE)2
#FALSE.input1  125.957730                   -2.434849                 0.022137337
#TRUE.input1     2.842223                    1.216113                -0.006686362
#FALSE.input2   68.807752                   -7.429319                26.486493218
#TRUE.input2    31.791633                  -18.595105                16.608600876
```

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, I'm obviously misunderstand it. Your question is not very clear. I'm very confused by use of the term "parameter" which doesn't match what I consider a model parameter.

Comment: Thank you, @Roland. You're right. The parameter I mentioned has nothing to do with a model's parameter. This parameter is a variable that I use to break the dataset in parts. Thank you for your input.

Comment: The models, however, are all built already. There're 20 models altogether. What I am trying to do is to loop over all the 20 models and access every single coefficient in all my model$coefficient so I can store every value in a matrix. I don't see how  lmList would take me closer to my goal, because as I see from the code you wrote, I can already access my coefficients. Not exactly the way you do, but in another way. The bottom line would be: how to get all the coefficients and put them in all into one single object? And I can't see how your code would do that. I'm not a good programmer so...

Comment: ) ... that may be the reason why I can't see it. But anyway, thank you for your time and effort to help. This community grows a lot because of people like you who are willing to help.

Comment: Also, maybe the question I posed was rather too complicated. I wanted to give a reproducible example and may have become attached to details. I could rather have given 5 models, all 6th-degree polynomials and then asked for a way to loop over all the models and extract all the coefficients so as to store them in, say, a matrix. In the end, I wanted a matrix with only one column in which every line would be a model coefficient. For my 5 models, I'd have a 30-line matrix, with coefficients from order 1 to 6 listed as first group for the first model, and repeat this for all remaining models.

Comment: If you have an lmList object you get the coefficients all in one object as I show in this answer. Refitting a few linear models is computationally cheap.